# Date picker similar to ICS

Tags: android

default date picker in ICS looks pretty good than date picker in 2.2,2.3 is it possible to create as such date picker in 2.2 and 2.3 using support libraries (or) any other choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these libraries :

[Better Picker](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers)

DialogFragments modeled after the 4.2 Alarm Clock TimePicker to improve UX for picking time, date, and numbers.

[Date picker back ported](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker)

Android ICS DatePicker backported to 2.2

Comment: When i imported library into eclipse it gives me following error-----------No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'numberPickerStyle'.

Comment: Which lib are you using?

Comment: just tell me the procedure to implement DatePickerMaster

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) library too.

Comment: Lot of friends are there to help me---->Ye Lin Aung, thank u friend

Comment: how to use HOLOEveryWhere

Comment: You can check its wiki https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Basic-migration-on-HoloEverywhere